# merge split divide by 4

Tags: java, mergesort

I'm solving an exercise for school, we need to implement a normal mergesort and top of that an extra method that does divide it by four instead of two elements.

The 2-split is working but I cannot manage to get the 4-split working. It would be great if someone can lead me into the right direction.

This is what I got so far:

```
public static void mergeSortNew(int[] a, int left, int right) { ;

    if (left < right) {
        int middle1 = (left + right) / 4;
        int middle2 = middle1 + 1 + middle1;
        int middle3 = middle2 + 1 + middle1;
        mergeSortNew(a, left, middle1);
        mergeSortNew(a, middle1, middle2);
        mergeSortNew(a, middle2, middle3);
        mergeSortNew(a, middle3, right);

        merge(a, left, middle1, middle2);
        merge(a, middle2, middle2 + middle1, middle3);
        merge(a, middle3, middle3 + middle1, right);
    }
}

public static void merge(int [] a, int left, int middle, int right) {

    int n1 = middle - left + 1;
    int n2 = right - middle;
    int[] leftHalf = new int[n1 + 1];
    int[] rightHalf = new int[n2 + 1];
    leftHalf[n1] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    rightHalf[n2] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        leftHalf[i] = a[left + i];
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
        rightHalf[j] = a[middle + j + 1];
    }

    int i = 0, j = 0;

    for (int k = left; k <= right; k++) {
        if (leftHalf[i] <= rightHalf[j]) {
            a[k] = leftHalf[i++];
        } else {
            a[k] = rightHalf[j++];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The math for the indexes would be a bit simpler if right == 1 + last index. The names could be changed from (left, right) to (bgn, end), since end normally means 1 + last index. For the mid points I use: `mid1 = bgn +(end+0-bgn)/4;` | `mid2 = mid1+(end+1-bgn)/4;` | `mid3 = mid2+(end+2-bgn)/4;` . This keeps runs sizes similar with the smaller runs on the left. For 7 elements, the split will be (1 2 2 2), with indexes (0 1 3 5 7). In the merge function, the end of run index check would use `<` instead of `<=`.

Comment: What's the point of splitting into 4 sub-arrays, when the normal one will also manage to do the same thing in recursive steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- remove the spurious `;` at the end of the prototype line
- your convention to have both `left` and `right` index values included is confusing. It is much simpler to use a convention where the first index is included and the last index is excluded, as is implicit in your recursive calls.
- the index used for the `merge` calls are incorrect: `middle2 + middle1` makes no sense as you are adding offsets, not lengths. Use this instead:

  ```
  merge(a, left, middle1, middle2);  // merge slice 0 and 1 into slice 01
  merge(a, middle2, middle3, right); // merge slice 2 and 3 into slice 23
  merge(a, left, middle2, right);    // merge slice 01 and 23
  ```
- in the `merge` method, you rely on sentinel values. This is incorrect, this approach is fundamentally flawed and should be banned. If the right slice contains values equal to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, the function will copy the sentinel from the left slice and will continue reading beyond the end of the left slice, causing an exception. You should instead test both index values and copy the remaining values once one of the slices has been copied completely.

Here is a modified version:

```java
// sort a portion of an array from `a[left]` included to `a[right]` excluded
public static void mergeSortNew(int[] a, int left, int right) {
    int length = right - left;
    if (length >= 2) {
        int middle1 = left + length / 4;
        int middle2 = left + length / 2;
        int middle3 = middle2 + length / 4;
        mergeSortNew(a, left, middle1);
        mergeSortNew(a, middle1, middle2);
        mergeSortNew(a, middle2, middle3);
        mergeSortNew(a, middle3, right);

        merge(a, left, middle1, middle2);  // merge slice 0 and 1 into slice 01
        merge(a, middle2, middle3, right); // merge slice 2 and 3 into slice 23
        merge(a, left, middle2, right);    // merge slice 01 and 23
    }
}

public static void merge(int[] a, int left, int middle, int right) {
    int n1 = middle - left;
    int n2 = right - middle;
    int[] leftHalf = new int[n1];
    int[] rightHalf = new int[n2];

    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        leftHalf[i] = a[left + i];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
        rightHalf[j] = a[middle + j];
    }

    int i = 0, j = 0, k = left;

    while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
        if (leftHalf[i] <= rightHalf[j]) {
            a[k++] = leftHalf[i++];
        } else {
            a[k++] = rightHalf[j++];
        }
    }
    while (i < n1) {
        a[k++] = leftHalf[i++];
    }
    while (j < n2) {
        a[k++] = rightHalf[j++];
    }
}
```

You would sort an array with

```
mergeSortNew(array, 0, array.length);
```

Comment: Thank you for correcting me, it makes much more sense now. We were supposed to use sentinels for the mergesort, so I will try to adjust your solution to my code.

Comment: @halaldin: you can add sentinels to the local arrays `leftHalf` and `rightHalf`, but if you keep the index tests, they will not be read.